# Handling Context Cancellation Across Layers

Tags: go, error-handling, concurrency

I'm working on a layered backend API with controllers, services, repositories etc.

### Context

Each method from these layers takes a `context.Context` as its first parameter that contains the **request context**. This is convenient cause any method can access various request-related data (like correlationID etc.)

Each **request context** has a timeout set by the `TimeoutMiddleware` below:

```golang
func TimeoutMiddleware(timeoutFn func(*gin.Context) time.Duration) gin.HandlerFunc {
    return func(c *gin.Context) {
        timeout := timeoutFn(c)
        ctx, cancel := context.WithTimeout(c.Request.Context(), timeout)
        defer cancel()

        c.Request = c.Request.WithContext(ctx)

        c.Next()
    }
}

func TimeoutFn(c *gin.Context) time.Duration {
    return conf.HTTPRouter.DefaultContextTimeout
}
```

### The challenge

The idea is to gracefully stop any ongoing operation if the request context times out.
From my understanding (that is very little) about context and concurrency, I've built this helper function:

```golang
package helpers

import "context"

// Checks for context cancellation and returns ctx.Err() if canceled.
func HandleContextCancel(ctx context.Context) error {
    select {
    case <-ctx.Done(): // If the context is canceled
        return ctx.Err() // return immediately with the canceled error.

    default: 
        return nil // Continue with the normal processing.
    }
}
```

In theory, if I want to stop any operation **ASAP**, I need to call this function **at the very beginning of every single method across the application** like this:

```golang
func DoSomething(ctx context.Context, ...) resterrors.RestErr {
if err := helpers.HandleContextCancel(ctx); err != nil {
    return resterrors.NewRequestTimeoutError(
        fmt.Errorf("DoSomething: %w", err),
    )
}
// ...
```

At the same time, I know in a repository that access a database, a **context** is required by most of the functions like `Query`, `QueryRow`, `Exec` ... like this:

```golang
rows, err := pgclient.GetSession().Query(ctx, query, param1, ...)
```

So, each time an error is raised in the line above, instead of just returning an `internal_server_error` with the error message, I must check if the error is not due to the context cancellation like this:

```golang
rows, err := pgclient.GetSession().Query(ctx, query, param1, ...)
if err != nil {
   return helpers.MapRepoError("DoSomething: Query Error:", err)
}
```

```golang
func MapRepoError(location string, err error) resterrors.RestErr {
    if errors.Is(err, context.DeadlineExceeded) {
        return resterrors.NewRequestTimeoutError(
            fmt.Errorf("%s request_timeout", location),
        )
    }
    return resterrors.NewInternalServerError(
        fmt.Errorf("%s %w", location, err),
    )
}
```

It looks a little bit redundant with the `HandleContextCancel` function what do you think about all this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need the `HandleContextCancel` function, you can simply do:

```
if ctx.Err()!=nil {
  // Context timed out or canceled. Return
  return ctx.Err()
}
```

If your other error handling functions wrap this error correctly (i.e. they implement the `Unwrap() error` method, then at the top level you can check if an error contains a timeout/cancellation error, and decide what type of error you would like to return. You don't have to do it at every layer.

Comment: Okay, so the context cancellation is only detected at the execution of the if statement then. Just out of curiosity, do you know a way to receive the cancellation "in real time" with a goroutine or something? Good point about the error wrapping, thank you so much!

Comment: @Big_Boulard, that would be done by listening (selecting) the `ctx.Done()` channel.